# How to keep Flutter app running between integration tests

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, integration-testing

Follow the example of [integration test](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction)

Problem: after each test is done, the app is destroyed, need to call `app.main()` on every test which is quite time-consuming.

Expected: only run `app.main()` once for all the tests. State is reserved between test.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Same for me. In addition, every time it run tests, it delete all app data

Comment: when I first created my integration test, the app stayed open and i just had to do a hot restart to run it again, which was really nice and faster. but after i restarted my computer, it won't do that anymore. i want it back!